# Ошибка импорта Pnumpy в python

Tags: python

Установил Pnumpy на Windows 10 (64bit) python 3.7. Во время импорта Pnumpy появляется ошибка:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#198>", line 1, in
import pnumpy
File "C:\Python379\lib\site-packages\pnumpy_init.py", line 57, in
import pnumpy._pnumpy as pnumpy
ImportError: DLL load failed: Can't find the module.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки. Или это всё?

Comment: @Кирилл Малышев это полный текст ошибки

Comment: Ошибки нет, всё уже установлено.

Comment: Всё установлено, но ошибка во время импорта модуля